# Need an anonymizer for my site

Tags: reverse-proxy, cdn

I have a website that I want to make public. However I don't want people to know its real location. Two solutions that could work were:

1. To find a free webhosting and store the web interface part there, and then keep the database and non-interface logic on my real site. However it seems like all free hostings do not let you use external database. At least I couldn't find any that would.
2. To find a free online reverse proxy that would hide the real IP of my site. However I failed to find any as well.

If you are aware of any of the above, or you know other solution, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Throw it on Amazon?

Comment: Point your domain at  a CDN (such as the free cloud front) and restrict access to your server so that only request coming though the CDN are allowed. That will effectively mask the actual IP-address of your server(s) from the general public as well as make your site appear *nearby* as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**. would easily work.

You need to **open your database to outside access** (bind-address for mysql). And then modify your web interface (in whatever language you wrote it) to **use the IP address of your database**'s server.

The possible drawbacks are that it can be slow to communicate with mysql this way, and the communication would be unsecured.

Comment: My database is open to outside access. The problem is that free hostings (at least those that I have tried, and I have tried about 30 of them) would not allow you to connect to external database. If you know one that does allow it, I would be more than happy to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you and your users are willing to use [Tor](http://tor.eff.org) you can use the Hidden Service facility to hide your location.